# Model returns null if I navigate away from page and come back

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to populate a drop-down list.  Initially, everything runs as I expect it to.  But, when I navigate away from the original view and come back, I get this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.' System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get
>   returned null.

I tried adding an if statement to account for a null model but that did not work. (I took it out for now)

Thank you in advance.

Model:

```
public class IndexDates
{
    public List<PeriodEndDates> ListForDropDown { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(IndexDates datesParam)
{
    using (PayrollEntities2 db = new PayrollEntities2())
    {
        DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.Now;

        var model = new IndexDates()
        {
            ListForDropDown = db.PeriodEndDates2
                                    .Where(x => x.periodEndDate <= todaysDate)
                                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.periodEndDate )
                                    .ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="schedule-bottom">
         <p>Period End Date: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ListForDropDown, new SelectList(Model.ListForDropDown, "periodEndDate", "periodEndDate"), "Select...", new { onChange = "selectedtext(this)" })</p>
    </div>
}
```

PayrollEntities2:

```
    public partial class PayrollEntities2 : DbContext
    {
        public PayrollEntities2()
        : base("name=PayrollEntities2")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<PeriodEndDates2> PeriodEndDates2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Home Controller Redirect:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Authorize(UsersAndDates userModel)
    {
        using (MasterTable db = new MasterTable())
        {
            var userDetails = db.PaybillUsers.Where(x => x.userName == userModel.userName && x.password == userModel.password).FirstOrDefault();

            var datesToDisplay = db.PeriodEndDates2
                                            .Where(x => x.ffsPayDate > DateTime.Now)
                                            .Select(x => new PayDates
                                            {
                                                PayDate = x.ffsPayDate,
                                                PeriodEndDate = x.periodEndDate
                                            })
                                            .FirstOrDefault();

            if (userDetails == null)
            {
                return View("Login", userModel);
            }
            else
            {
                Session["userID"] = userDetails.userName.ToString();
                Session["payDate"] = datesToDisplay.PayDate.ToString();
                Session["endDate"] = datesToDisplay.PeriodEndDate.ToString();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Likely a Post-Redirect-Get problem.

Comment: This might be the issue.  I post redirect from my HomeController to a new controller.  How do you consider going about fixing this?

Comment: I posted the redirect in my edit

Comment: How do you navigate away and come back? Go to another site then hi the back button? Or go elsewhere in the app then use a link?

Comment: I have two layout pages that list ActionLinks at the top of the page.  My default layout page has 4 actionlinks inside of it one being a login page.  The other layout page is for when someone has logged in successfully.  When I first run the application, I log in and everything is fine.  When I click a link to another page and come back to the original page, I get the error saying my model returned null.

Comment: When you go back to the Index page, how are you passing the IndexDates datesParam value?

Comment: Which of the view is the dropdown in? you have `Index`, `Dashboard`, `Login` but the question did not say the name of the View where the dropdown is. if redirect is the problem you can consider `TempData`. if you question can be clear enough I can write you an answer

Answer (score 0):

I **think** it's because you use `using (PayrollEntities2 db = new PayrollEntities2())`
instead of just declaring it.